# Webdriverio element needs to be type of string?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Webdriverio element needs to be type of string?

My code is as followed:

```
describe('Test Contact Us form WebdriverUni', function() {
  it.only('Should be able to submit a successful submission via contact us form', function(done) {
    browser.pause(5000);
      var firstNameTextField = $("[name='first_name']");
      var firstNameTextField = "[name='last_name']";

      browser.setValue(firstNameTextField, 'Joe');
```

Using the following code: var and $, I seem to be receiving the following exception: 'element needs to be type of String'.

Also the following fails with the same exception:

```
var firstNameTextField = browser.element("[name='last_name']");
```

However the following works:

```
browser.setValue("[name='first_name']", 'Joe');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see, webdriver setValue takes a selector that must be for type String.

When you use this piece of code: `var firstNameTextField = $("[name='first_name']");` you are getting an object, not a string.

When however you call it like that: `browser.setValue("[name='first_name']", 'Joe');` you are providing a selector of type String. And it works.

So, you should probably change your variable to `var firstNameTextField = "[name='first_name']";`

EDIT:

I also noticed you are using the same variable name twice here:

```
  var firstNameTextField = $("[name='first_name']");
  var firstNameTextField = "[name='last_name']";
```

Shouldn't the second one be lastNameTextField?

Comment: Chris thanks so much! The variables listed above with the same name was just for illustration purposes, thanks again for spending the time to create a detailed answer.

Comment: how would I use $ to setup my variables according to: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/$.html ?

Comment: If you want to use the element you get from `var firstNameTextField = $("[name='first_name']");` then:

Instead of `browser.setValue(firstNameTextField, 'Joe');`
Do it like: `firstNameTextField.setValue('Joe');`